# Cant add Community.CsharpSqlite.WP7.dll to my WP7 project

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone

I have a WP7 project, which runs fine, but when I try to add reference to Community.CsharpSqlite.WP7.dll I get

> A Reference to a higher version or incomptible assembly cannot be added to the project

But this is a WP7 file I am trying to add?

I got it here, which is a cross platform app

https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/MWC/Dependencies/Community.CsharpSqlite

Also tried

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/tree/master/lib/wp7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't add it, BUT you can build it yourself.

The project is located here - [C# SQLite project](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/)

If you look in the source you will find the Windows Phone project that you can compile your own DLL.

Answer (score 1):

The last SQLite client release that I see on CodePlex was in December 2010, so even though you're looking at DLLs that were posted 4 to 10 months ago on these other sites, it's possible that they are using the Windows Phone 7.0 code base and you are targeting the Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango) SDK.  Various DLLs changed between 7.0 and 7.1 and if the DLLs you're looking at were in fact built while targeting 7.0, they may have older and incompatible references if you're targeting 7.1.  I suggest trying to build the SQLite source code into your project using the 7.1 SDK.

Also note that neither the google or codeplex projects for SQLite are the official code bases either.  You should use the DLLs or source code from the official site if possible: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: From what I know the SQLite DLLs are native DLLs, so he won't be able to use them with a WP7.5 project. The google project is actually a port of the SQLite C code to C# which can be compiled for WP7.x.

Comment: So which release is adviceable to use for sqlite?

Comment: The ported C# version of SQLite only has one version of sqlite thats 3.7.7.1